# How to run buildr tests with -ea flag (enable assertions)

Tags: buildr

Does anyone know how to enableassertions during testing? I'm trying to use buildr to for a lucene based project and I get the following exception:

[junit] Test class requires enabled assertions, enable globally (-ea) or for Solr/Lucene subpackages only:

I've tried from the command line:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-ea buildr
```

and putting the following in my buildfile:

```
ENV['JAVA_OPTS'] ||= '-enableAssertions'
```

I'm using the java version of buildr (1.4.12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ugh, 2 seconds after submitting this I figured out the solution:

```
  test.using :java_args => [ '-ea' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with SOLR and eclipse, solution is exactly the same.

In package explorer right click on project:
Run As->Run Configurations...->JUnit->ProjectName->Arguments(second tab)->VM arguments

Type in :`-ea`